# How to add react native project into Docker?

Tags: docker, react-native, dockerfile

I need to add my project to the docker container. I added a dockerfile into my app and add the following code lines. I don't have good knowledge of docker commands. I follow the guidelines from this video.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSIC3JTQnPs&t=3s). I need to do these things to react-native project. Please give me some step by step to solve this problem.

**This is my dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

COPY package.json /myapp
COPY App.js /myapp

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

**My project Structure**

[image: My project Structure]

Comment: yeah, I tried that command and successfully added it into container. But when I run it localhost or other links not working.

Comment: Is there any tutorial to follow?

Comment: Ok, I'll try these things. One thing to know, Is it correct dockerfile code for react native app?

Comment: I'll add an image for that. please wait. It is just a fresh react native app. I'm not change anything.

Comment: I add an image. Please give me instruction to add a react native app into docker.

Comment: ok, sir. I newly execute "docker build -t my-app . && docker run -it my-app" this code line now.

Comment: do I need to add react-native run-android into dockerfile? if not How it will run on android emulator?

Comment: sir, it works fine up to now.  it starts the react-native server and not run it on the android emulator? what should I do?

Comment: I just realized that you have a react-native app and not a react app as I was thinking. I am not aware if it is possible to achieve what you want, so you should wait for an answer of someone more expert than I am. I would remove also my comments to avoid confusion for future readers.

Comment: No please don't remove. I need that too. because I tried it with the react app too.

Comment: Please add that localhost setting command

Comment: `docker run -it -p HOST:CONTAINER my-app` and replace `HOST`, `CONTAINER` with the appropriate ports.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I'll try this too and let you know.

Comment: Did you get more information about this?

Comment: No, I didn't find any. @LautaroZarandon